# How to delete particular column family data from google bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Hi i recently started exploring Google Bigtable features.

If I want to delete particular column family data corresponding to  particular row key of the table then how can i achieve this.

Using this command I am able to get all records

cbt -project my-project -instance my-instance lookup my-table rowkey

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the data from a specific column and row, you can use the [`cbt deletecolumn`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#delete_all_cells_in_a_column) command

```
cbt deletecolumn <table-id> <row-key> <family> <column>
```

Example:

```
 cbt deletecolumn mobile-time-series phone#4c410523#20190501 stats_summary os_name
```

There are more example commands in the [cbt reference guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference).

Comment: If I specify cbt deletecolumn <table-id> <row-key> <family> then  it will delete all the records of that column family from that rowkey of the corresponding table . right? Can we also do it programmatically?

Comment: I don't believe deleting the entire family like that is supported. You could probably write a quick script to grab all the columns in that column family for the row then delete them with the command I provided.

Comment: I have used this cbt -instance my-instance read my-table prefix=abc | grep '^abc' | xargs -I '{}' cbt -instance my-instance deleterow my-table {} ... but it does not delete row. Please suggest

Comment: I want to delete columns of specific column family only . Please help me with this. I am stuck